# Visual Studio will not start

Tags: visual-studio

The IT department upgraded my computer from windows 7 to windows 10, after that all my different visual studio versions(2012, 2013,2015 and 2017) stopped working, when I click on them I see the initializing logo then I get the general exception:

```
Exception has bee thrown by the target of an invocation
```

After some investigation there was some suggestions that the problem was related to the system variables specifically to **PATH** being to long, I checked this and mine is under 2000 characters.

I tried repairing VS, **uninstall/reinstall** but the error wont go away, after that I downloaded https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493 to get the logs and here is the full exception:

```
Beginning of the log. Start Time: 11/6/2017 12:07:41 PM
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:41 PM: Current OptIn value is 1
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Commandline arguments = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Parent process name = vs_Enterprise
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Parent process product version = 15.4.27004.2006
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: CampaignId = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Caught Exception: Type = XamlParseException, Message = Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception., StackTrace =    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args)
InnerException:Type = COMException, Message = UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980406), StackTrace =    at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CompleteRender()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CreateChannels()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaSystem.ConnectChannels(MediaContext mc)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext..ctor(Dispatcher dispatcher)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.From(Dispatcher dispatcher)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.VerifyAPIReadWrite()
   at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Add(Visual visual)
   at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement element)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.Add(Object collection, XamlType collectionType, Object value, XamlType valueXamlType)
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: General Failure. Message:Add value to collection of type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection' threw an exception. Callstack:    at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.RewrapException(Exception e, IXamlLineInfo lineInfo, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(XamlReader xamlReader, IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.LoadBaml(XamlReader xamlReader, Boolean skipJournaledProperties, Object rootObject, XamlAccessLevel accessLevel, Uri baseUri)
   at System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.LoadBaml(Stream stream, ParserContext parserContext, Object parent, Boolean closeStream)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, ProgramOptions options)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Program.Run(String[] args) Inner Message:UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88980406) Internal Exception:    at System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel.SyncFlush()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CompleteRender()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.CreateChannels()
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaSystem.ConnectChannels(MediaContext mc)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext..ctor(Dispatcher dispatcher)
   at System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.From(Dispatcher dispatcher)
   at System.Windows.Media.Visual.VerifyAPIReadWrite()
   at System.Windows.Media.VisualCollection.Add(Visual visual)
   at System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection.AddInternal(UIElement element)
   at MS.Internal.Xaml.Runtime.ClrObjectRuntime.Add(Object collection, XamlType collectionType, Object value, XamlType valueXamlType)
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: Sending Watson Bucket with:
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P1  = vs_setup_bootstrapper
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P2  = 1.12.158.19022
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P3  = 
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P4  = Install
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P5  = https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/installer
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P6  = n/a
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P7  = 5002
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P8  = -2146233087
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P9  = Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Enterprise
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: P10 = VisualStudio.15.Release
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: Including dmp file
VisualStudio Bootstrapper:11/6/2017 12:07:42 PM: Watson: Including Log : C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_bootstrapper_20171106120741.log
```

Looking at the exception UCEERR_RENDERTHREADFAILURE I found this article https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2013/11/18/wpf-render-thread-failures/ that says could be related to video drivers, but after updating all my drivers the problem still persist.

Does anyone had a similar issue before that can bring some light to this problem?

Comment: I also noticed that the same error was happening with SQL management studio, unfortunately  after 3 days of trying different things we were unable to fix the issue, the only solution we got was to do a fresh install of windows 10 and reinstall everything. We think the problem was related to the program used to create an image of the data and programs before the upgrade to windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue. visual studio and visual studio installer cannot launch after Upgrading windows 7 to windows 10.

I installed the newest [.netframework 4.7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-framework-runtime), the issue got fixed. 
 Hope it helps

Comment: +1 I don't have a way to try this but I also think this can be the solution since it was not only VS it was anything relying on .netframework

Answer (score 0):

You might try reinstalling one of the visual studio versions to see if this fixes the problem.  Sometimes when you upgrade Windows the registry gets corrupted so already installed programs will stop working.  I have not had a problem running VS2012 and VS2017 on Windows 10, so they should work fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I just updated my question, I already tried repairing the installation then reinstalling but that didn't work.